# Facing issue in restarting the nginx server after few changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy

Made few changes in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file like changing the listen port number and added few parameters to access the Kibana.

when i m restarting the nginx server `sudo systemctl start nginx`, its throwing error like

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-154:~$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-154:~$ sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-154:~$
```

this is the template added into the file

[image]